# What is the name of this " <?= " in php?

Tags: php, operator-keyword

For printing any PHP variable the following syntax is used sometimes

```
<?= $x ?>
```

Can anyone please explain when should I use this instead of

```
<?php echo $x; ?>
```

and what the name of that operator `<?=` ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: It is simple short opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's a "short tag"; this one is an abbreviation for `"<?php echo"`. You need to be careful when using it or any other short tags as not all servers are configured to render them correctly.

A bit more info can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 0):

it's fast echo.
You can use it with html. 
`<div class="<?=$your_class"></div>`